# Liberty Directory is expected here

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I've just installed the **MobileFirstStudio** **plugin** for eclipse.
As far as I can see it has installed correctly.

After **restarting** eclipse I get the following error in MobileFirst

> Console: Liberty directory is expected here:
>   C:\eclipse\plugins\com.worklight.worklight-artifacts_7.0.0.00-20150312-0731.jar\liberty\wlp

I see the jar exists and I unpacked the jar and `liberty\wlp` path exists with other folders and files inside like bin, lib readme.txt etc...

I tried installing the **Webshpere Liberty Profile plugin** as well, but I still get the error.

Can anyone help me with this error? What does it mean and what is missing?

Comment: Why did you try installing "Webshpere Liberty Profile plugin". How is it related?

Comment: What is your Eclipse version? What is your Worklight version?

Comment: It's probably not related. The error mentioned Liberty was missing, so I thought this could fix it? I'm new to this. Eclipse Kepler, worklight v7.0

Comment: How did you install the MobileFirst plug-in?

Comment: It would also be useful to know what version of Java you are using.  I have not seen this specific error before, but sometimes people have problems using MobileFirst Platform 7.0 if they try to use it with Java 8 (MFP 7.0 only supports Java 6 and Java 7).

Comment: I updated the plugin from https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-studio and the error disappeared.

Answer (score -2):

I installed the plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace per the instructions provided in comments by @user3511041. The plugin is available at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-studio.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11278326)

Comment: It very much answers it. Read the comments.